# IValueConverter calculate new size for TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resize, ivalueconverter

I am trying to use the IValueConverter to calculate a new width for a TextBlock depending on the width on a Grid. But I always get this exception:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '264' and line position '76'.*

I striped down the CalMeetingSize to everything but I still get the error. So I assume i making something wrong in the xaml? Can someone give me a hint?

```
<Grid x:Name="CalBackGround" Margin="163,30,0,0">
```

...

```
<TextBlock Height="18" Text="{Binding subject}" 
   Width="{Binding Path=Width,  
   ElementName=CalBackGround,  
   Converter={StaticResource CalMeetingSizeKey}}"
/>
```

...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CalMeetingSize x:Key="CalMeetingSizeKey"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
public class CalMeetingSize : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return 200;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the `Inner Exception`?

Comment: Are you snippets the same order as in your xaml? If yes you are using your resource before it is defined. Best thing would be to put `<Window.Resources>` always as the first child of `<Window>`.

Comment: The question is why you want to do that at all. Is the TextBlock not a child element of the Grid that can be resized by ordinary layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you declared the Window.Resources before the first use in XAML so that it is known.
Also build you application once after adding the resource before using it helps sometimes fixing build-errors

You must also not bind to an element's `Width`, but always to its `ActualWidth`. Width is initialized to `NaN` and won't work here.

Comment: The XAML is not correct, because it binds to the Grid's Width, which isn't set and hence has its default value `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to CalBackGround's `ActualWidth` property, not `Width`.